# New versus Returning Users in Looker Studio with GA4 connection

Tags: google-analytics, dimensions, looker

I would like to set up the 'user type' dimension to display new versus returning users. Currently, I have a Looker Studio report with a GA4 connection. The query I wrote doesn't seem to be working

`CASE WHEN First session date=Date THEN "New Visitor" ELSE "Returning Visitor" END`

Is there a calculation for this? Any ideas?

The query:
`CASE WHEN First session date=Date THEN "New Visitor" ELSE "Returning Visitor" END` 
I would like to have a stacked table displaying new/returning visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a new metric, probably named `Returning Users` by subtracting the `new users` from `total users`.

If you don't know how to create one, follow these steps:

1. Drop the table component onto your report
2. In the **Metrics** section, click `+ Add a metric`
3. Click the `+ Create Field` button at the bottom of the list. Additional pane will open.
4. Name your new metric
5. In the **Formula** free text field, enter `Total Users - New Users`. Allow the application to autofill the metrics when typing.
6. Make sure you see a green check and click `Apply`.

Your new metric is now available to drop into any chart or component you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! This metric does not work for me.